# Passing empty NSIndexPath in userInfo of a notification in NSNotificationCenter

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, nsindexpath, userinfo

I have a specific scenario, when an order list (`NSMutableArray`) is empty and therefore the selected index (`NSIndexPath`) should also be empty (I'm using `nil`). I am passing those data using `NSNotificationCenter` to trigger an update in a table elsewhere in the app.

However, I am receiving an error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary
>   initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from
>   objects[1]'

How can I pass an empty index via `NSNotificationCenter`?

```
NSMutableArray *filteredAndSortedOrders = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSIndexPath *selectedIndex = nil;//[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]]//The problem with this is that it's non-empty
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_RELOAD_TABLE_AND_DATA
                                                    object:self
                                                  userInfo:@{
                                                             @"filteredAndSortedOrders":[filteredandSortedOrders copy],
                                                             @"selectedIndex":selectedIndex
                                                             }
 ];
```

Comment: You should check if `selectedIndex` == nil, your userInfo has only `@"filteredAndSortedOrders":[self.filteredandSortedOrders copy]`

Comment: Yes, `selectedIndex`==nil and that is causing the error. But I am looking for a proper way of passing empty NSIndexPath via notification.

Comment: Why you need to put the selectedIndex to your info. You can check in thê observer if has not object for `selectedIndex` key instead of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `NSIndexPath` with with a negative value and check on receiver side that the value is negative.

**Code:**

```
NSIndexPath *selectedIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:-1 inSection:-1];
```

Comment: beat me to it :)